# google maps api allow non google users to edit map in iframe

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3, google-maps-markers, geocaching

I have a google map where I am getting users to log where certain events happen when they post them in a blog sort of setup.  Not all of my users have google accounts and you cannot edit the map from an iframe so my question is there any way to allow any user to edit a map (drop a pin in a location) straight from an iframe.

If not is there any way to allow non-google users to edit a public map?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using the Google Maps JavaScript API v3 to create a map that you are delivering from your website, there is no requirement for users of your website to have a Google account. If you make the map publicly available and provide the ability to add dynamic markers, that functionality should be available to anyone that visits your site/map web page.

Are you delivering a map that is hosted by Google in some way?

Comment: yes I was just using an iframe to the google hosted map.  I'll check out the javascript APIs though

Comment: got it I didn't see the JS API initially